# Save data into multiple tables

Tags: c#, nhibernate-mapping, one-to-many

I have 2 db tables and class structure working with nhibernate as follows.

DB

[image]

C# poco classes are as follow.

**Customer Class**

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Mobile { get; set; }
    public virtual string Phone { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual Address BillingAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }
}
```

**Address Class**

```
public class Address
{
    public virtual int AddressID { get; set; }
    public virtual string AddressLine { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual string State { get; set; }
    public virtual int ZIP { get; set; }
    public virtual string Fax { get; set; }
    public virtual string Country { get; set; }
}
```

**Mapping Files**

customer.hbm.xml

```
  <class name="Customer" table="Customers">
    <id name="CustomerID">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="CustomerName" length="100" />
    <property name="Title" length="10" />
    <property name="FirstName" length="60" />
    <property name="LastName" length="60" />
    <property name="Mobile" length="15" />
    <property name="Phone" length="15" />
    <property name="Email" length="100" />
    <many-to-one name="BillingAddress" class="Address" />
    <many-to-one name="ShippingAddress" class="Address" />
  </class>
```

address.hbm.xml

```
  <class name="Address" table="Addresses">
    <id name="AddressID">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="AddressLine" length="255" />
    <property name="City" length="30" />
    <property name="State" length="30" />
    <property name="ZIP" />
    <property name="Fax" length="15" />
    <property name="country" length="50" />
  </class>
```

I am creating the database tables using nhibernate session. Tables are creating fine. with the above structure, If I want to save a customer with 2 address types specified, how can I save that 1 customer to customers table and 2 address to addresses table? See the following example code.

```
Address b_address = new Address();
Address s_address = new Address();
Customer customer = new Customer();

b_address.addressLine = "No.23, New Road";
b_address.City = "Newyork";
// more data

s_address.addressLine = "No.54, Old Road";
// more data

customer.CustomerName = "David";
// more customer data
customer.BillingAddress = b_address;
customer.ShippingAddress = s_address;

//saving the session.
session.save(customer)
```

The above code only insert the data into customers table. How would I make this insert data to both customers and addresses table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to put `casacde` setting in play. Just change the many-to-one mapping this way:

```
<many-to-one name="BillingAddress" class="Address" cascade="all"  />
<many-to-one name="ShippingAddress" class="Address" cascade="all"  />
```

This will allow NHibernate to persist new `Address`es and update existing, while only calling `Customer` instance to be saved/updated.

Comment: Fantastic. Btw, what are the other options in cascade that we can use?

Comment: Here is the doc http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone. extract: `cascade="all|none|save-update|delete"`. **All** is probably more suitable in your case, because when customer is deleted all his address should go as well.

Comment: I have another case in my another table where all, save-update or delete not work. Table1 is there with full of data. Table2 has many to one relation to it. I just want to keep the primary key from Table1 but should not add new data to Table1. Which one I can use? (think of Addresses -> [many-to-one] -> Countries) country table is already with countries filled in. Address table should contain the primary key of country. And when load data, full country object should be loaded using the Country POCO.

Comment: Thanks men, Any way I got the answer to that. Cascade="none" with insert and update true worked. (insert="true" update="true" cascade="none")